Python code not connecting to MySQL when using another account
I'm working on a python windows app. I have two accounts for my database built with MySQL workbench: host and user. The user account would be used on other computers while the host account has the most administrator privilages. I tried running the code with the user account through Visual Studio Code but it gave me an error through the terminal:
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'public ip address' (timed out)")

I'm not sure if I'm missing something. It works well with localhost but when I tried using the public ip address (which from what I've read, could be useful to make the app executable on other computers besides mine), it gave me an error. I also made sure I had "bind-address: 0.0.0.0" on my.ini, ehich originally didn't have it so I had to add it in.

Please include both the full stacktrace error and the code.

This sounds more like a network config issue, rather than a code or mysql problen. The error message basically says that there was no answer from mysql whatsoever.

I'm not too sure with VSCode in this case, check and see if MySQL server is listening on the correct port first (default is 3306)
netstat -an | find "3306"

And look for address:
0.0.0.0:3306

Another possible problem could be to do with user permission and Firewall.
Check with the step above first.
